# Avoiding divergent solutions with odeint? shooting method

Tags: python, methods, ode, odeint

I am trying to solve an equation in Python. Basically what I want to do is to solve the equation:

```
(1/x^2)*d(Gam*dL/dx)/dx)+(a^2*x^2/Gam-(m^2))*L=0
```

This is the Klein-Gordon equation for a massive scalar field in a Schwarzschild spacetime. It suppose that we know `m` and `Gam=x^2-2*x`. The initial/boundary condition that I know are `L(2+epsilon)=1` and `L(infty)=0`. Notice that the asymptotic behavior of the equation is

```
L(x-->infty)-->Exp[(m^2-a^2)*x]/x and Exp[-(m^2-a^2)*x]/x
```

Then, if `a^2>m^2` we will have oscillatory solutions, while if `a^2 < m^2` we will have a divergent and a decay solution.

What I am interested is in the decay solution, however when I am trying to solve the above equation transforming it as a system of first order differential equations and using the shooting method in order to find the "a" that can give me the behavior that I am interested about, I am always having a divergent solution. I suppose that it is happening because `odeint` is always finding the divergent asymptotic solution. Is there a way to avoid or tell to `odeint` that I am interested in the decay solution? If not, do you know a way that I could solve this problem? Maybe using another method for solving my system of differential equations? If yes, which method?

Basically what I am doing is to add a new system of equation for "a"

```
(d^2a/dx^2=0, da/dx(2+epsilon)=0,a(2+epsilon)=a_0)
```

in order to have "a" as a constant. Then I am considering different values for "a_0" and asking if my boundary conditions are fulfilled.

Thanks for your time. Regards,

Luis P.

Comment: This is more a question about physics or scientific computing. What code do you use for the shooting? How do you incorporate the value at infinity?

Answer (score 0):

I am incorporating the value at infinity considering the assimptotic behavior, it means that I will have a relation between the field and its derivative. I will post the code for you if it is helpful:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().magic('reset -sf')
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from math import *
from scipy.integrate import ode
```

These are initial conditions for Schwarzschild. The field is invariant under reescaling, then I can use $L(2+\epsilon)=1$

```
def init_sch(u_sch):
    om = u_sch[0]
    return np.array([1,0,om,0]) #conditions near the horizon, [L_c,dL/dx,a,da/dx]
```

These are our system of equations

```
def F_sch(IC,r,rho_c,m,lam,l,j=0,mu=0):
    L = IC[0]
    ph = IC[1]
    om = IC[2]
    b = IC[3]

    Gam_sch=r**2.-2.*r

    dR_dr = ph
    dph_dr = (1./Gam_sch)*(2.*(1.-r)*ph+L*(l*(l+1.))-om**2.*r**4.*L/Gam_sch+(m**2.+lam*L**2.)*r**2.*L)
    dom_dr = b
    db_dr = 0.
    return [dR_dr,dph_dr,dom_dr,db_dr]
```

Then I try for different values of "om" and ask if my boundary conditions are fulfilled. p_sch are the parameters of my model. In general what I want to do is a little more complicated and in general I will need more parameters that in the just massive case. Howeve I need to start with the easiest which is what I am asking here

```
p_sch = (1,1,0,0) #[rho_c,m,lam,l], lam and l are for a more complicated case 
ep = 0.2
ep_r = 0.01
r_end = 500
n_r = 500000
n_omega = 1000
omega = np.linspace(p_sch[1]-ep,p_sch[1],n_omega)
r = np.linspace(2+ep_r,r_end,n_r)
tol = 0.01
a = 0

for j in range(len(omega)): 
    print('trying with $omega =$',omega[j])
    omeg = [omega[j]]
    ini = init_sch(omeg)
    Y = odeint(F_sch,ini,r,p_sch,mxstep=50000000)
    print Y[-1,0]
#Here I ask if my asymptotic behavior is fulfilled or not. This should be basically my value at infinity
    if abs(Y[-1,0]*((p_sch[1]**2.-Y[-1,2]**2.)**(1/2.)+1./(r[-1]))+Y[-1,1]) < tol:
        print(j,'times iterations in omega')
        print("R'(inf)) = ", Y[-1,0])        
        print("\omega",omega[j])
        omega_1 = [omega[j]] 
        a = 10
        break           
    if a > 1:
        break
```

Basically what I want to do here is to solve the system of equations giving different initial conditions and find a value for "a=" (or "om" in the code) that should be near to my boundary conditions. I need this because after this I can give such initial guest to a secant method and try to fiend a best value for "a". However, always that I am running this code I am having divergent solutions that it is, of course, a behavior that I am not interested. I am trying the same but considering the scipy.integrate.solve_vbp, but when I run the following code:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().magic('reset -sf')
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import *
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp

def bc(ya,yb,p_sch):
    m = p_sch[1]
    om = p_sch[4]
    tol_s = p_sch[5]
    r_end = p_sch[6]

    return np.array([ya[0]-1,yb[0]-tol_s,ya[1],yb[1]+((m**2-yb[2]**2)**(1/2)+1/r_end)*yb[0],ya[2]-om,yb[2]-om,ya[3],yb[3]])

def fun(r,y,p_sch):
    rho_c = p_sch[0]
    m = p_sch[1]
    lam = p_sch[2]
    l = p_sch[3]

    L = y[0]
    ph = y[1]
    om = y[2]
    b = y[3]

    Gam_sch=r**2.-2.*r

    dR_dr = ph
    dph_dr = (1./Gam_sch)*(2.*(1.-r)*ph+L*(l*(l+1.))-om**2.*r**4.*L/Gam_sch+(m**2.+lam*L**2.)*r**2.*L)
    dom_dr = b
    db_dr = 0.*y[3]
    return np.vstack((dR_dr,dph_dr,dom_dr,db_dr))

eps_r=0.01
r_end = 500
n_r = 50000
r = np.linspace(2+eps_r,r_end,n_r)
y = np.zeros((4,r.size))
y[0]=1
tol_s = 0.0001
p_sch= (1,1,0,0,0.8,tol_s,r_end)


sol = solve_bvp(fun,bc, r, y, p_sch)
```

I am obtaining this error: ValueError: `bc` return is expected to have shape (11,), but actually has (8,).
ValueError: `bc` return is expected to have shape (11,), but actually has (8,).